# phpmyadmin/ mysql how to copy a table with all its constraints

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I tried to copy a table which is connected to another table through a foreign key using

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM table 2";
```

but when I run this query it copies every thing but the constraints are not copied.

Is there any way I can run a script through phpmyadmin or write a function that preserve the constraints and the references ?

Comment: I tried this but I have a problem in the constraint relationship                       $query = "CREATE TABLE  table_copy LIKE table1 ";
    
$query1= "ALTER TABLE table_copy ADD PRIMARY KEY (`req_id`),
ADD KEY `req_s_f` (`req_stage`) ";
$query2 = "ALTER TABLE table_copy MODIFY `req_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4";
    
$query3= "ALTER TABLE  table_copy ADD CONSTRAINT `req_stage_f` FOREIGN KEY(`req_stage`) REFERENCES `stages`(`stage_id`) ";                        The last query can't create the reference

Answer (score 1):

Within phpMyAdmin, if you go to the table you wish to copy and click the "Operations" tab, there should be a section "Copy table to (database.table)"

Here you will be able to copy the table with the same constraints as the table you are trying to copy.

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEYs` get messy since they can work either way.  That is, the table being copied may be referencing some other table *or vice versa*.

One of those cases cannot be copied, since the reference cannot link simultaneously to both the original table and the new.